How does @ContentChild() able to accept an Injection Token in v12 but not v14?
I an not sure how does @ContentChild accept an InjectionToken in Angular v14. I could not find suitable update document.
I have a WIDGET_TOKEN
 export const WIDGET_TOKEN = new InjectionToken("WIDGET_TOKEN")

VelocityWidgetComponent is provided for injection token WIDGET_TOKEN
@Component({
  providers:[
    {provide:WIDGET_TOKEN,useExisting:VelocityWidgetComponent}
  ]
})
export class VelocityWidgetComponent implements OnInit {}

WidgetWrapperComponent token wraps VelocityWidgetComponent and tries to access it through @ContentChild
@Component({
  styleUrls: ['./widget-wrapper.component.css']
})
export class WidgetWrapperComponent implements OnInit {
  @ContentChild(WIDGET_TOKEN,{static:true}) widget:any;
}

--* app.component.html *--
 <app-widget-wrapper>
    <app-velocity-widget></app-velocity-widget>
 </app-widget-wrapper>

In Angular v12 example it throws an error. I understand this error, as per docs @ContentChild does not accept a non-string token as selector.
But how Angular v14 example accept a non-string token as selector? and how does the dependency resolved when WIDGET_TOKEN is provided in the VelocityWidgetComponent which is child of the WidgetWrapperComponent (requested component). I mean if the same token had need used as Dependency Injection through constructor DI example it will throw error NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken WIDGET_TOKEN!

For Angular 10 and Angular 14, the types are different, provider is only present in 14 but not in 10.
For Angular 10
export interface ContentChildDecorator {
    ...
    (selector: Type<any>|Function|string, opts?: {read?: any, static?: boolean}): any;
    new(selector: Type<any>|Function|string, opts?: {read?: any, static?: boolean}): ContentChild;
    ...
}

For Angular 14
export interface ContentChildDecorator {
    ...
    (selector: ProviderToken<unknown>|Function|string, opts?: {read?: any, static?: boolean}): any;
    new(selector: ProviderToken<unknown>|Function|string,
  opts?: {read?: any, static?: boolean}): ContentChild;
    ...
}

As for the second question, the providers array, applies for the base component and all its children, so I guess it looks at the providers array of the content children and selects the appropriate injection. I don't have knowledge of where it does the logic, this is just my guess!

Thanks @Naren Murali. I have updated the second part of the question

@sql_dummy I checked the code and the angular 14 stackblitz works as expected, I am not able to access in constructor, since it does not exist on widget wrapper, but on velocity component, only way we can access this is through the ContentChild which looks at the injector of the child and gets the component!

@sql_dummy  same goes for angular 10 example

Any idea why docs do not  have the update that the non string injection token can be used in @ContentChild

@sql_dummy Check the docs ContentChild it accepts 5 types, below line The following selectors are supported. you can see!
